# PHP loop through JSON multidimensional array and load data on button click

Tags: php, json, loops, click

Basically I'm retrieving a JSON content from a php call using some custom API. The arrays are all social posts. The code I'm using at the moment displays all of them at once when the page is loaded. I Would like to show them 10 or 20 at time, depending on my need, I'm using a PHP foreach loop to put the data on the page.  I would like to get the first 10 indexes (from `[0]` to  `[10]`) and setup a button to load the next indexes  `[11], [12], [13]...`, let's say 10 at time( from `[11]` to  `[20]`, from `[21]` to  `[30]` )  at each click. Is this possible?

The JSON content looks like this:

```
 Array
  (
    [comments] => Array
      (
        [0] => Array
          (
             [type] => instagram
             [author] => Rick B.
             [message] =>  #follow4follow #followme
             [authorImage] => https://image.load.here/image.jpg
          )

        [1] => Array
          (
             [type] => twitter
             [author] => John Tesla
             [message] => Welcome to the Fine Living
             [authorImage] => https://image.load.here/image.jpg
          )

       [2] => Array
          (
             [type] => facebook
             [author] => Rob Roy
             [message] => Buscando el perfect sunset! 
             [authorImage] => https://image.load.here/image.jpg
          )

       [...]

     [180] => Array
          (
             [type] => vine
             [author] => Joe Fox
             [message] => Bom dia insônia! #bomdia
             [authorImage] => https://image.load.here/image.jpg
          )
       )
    )
```

This is the (semplified) code that i'm using:

```
<!-- load content loop -->

<?php if(count($comments) > 0): ?>
    <?php 
      $counter = 0;
      foreach($comments as $comment): ?>
    <?php
        $type = $comment['type'];
        $author = $comment['author'];
        $message = $comment['message'];
        $avatar = $comment['authorImage'];

        $counter++;

    ?>
    <!-- write content -->
    <?php 
        // need to repeat this block of code eg. 10 times 
        // and not eg: 180 (is the actual number of indexes [0], [1], [2] in my JSON array.
        echo '<div class="social ' . $type . '">
                <p class="icon"><img src="'.$type.'".jpg"/></p>
                <p class="avatar">' . $avatar . '</p>
                <p class="author">Posted by ' . $author . '</p>
                <p class="message">' . $message . '</p>
              </div>';

    ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <h2>There are no comments yet</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: store json array inside a hidden field using json_encode()..  and get its value and build html by listening to .click fuction of jquery in javascript

Comment: @Alex Kashin -  Hi, i edited my post to be more clear, i need to show eg: 10 blocks of `.mycontents_xx` at time

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function doMyStuff()
{
    // Doing all your other stuff in here.. 
    $currentIndex = 30;
    getData($currentIndex);
}    

function getData(currentIndex) {
    $maxIndex = currentIndex + 10;
    for($x = $currentIndex; $x < maxIndex; $x++) {
        echo '<div class="'. $comment['content{$x}'] .'"><p>Content..'..'</p></div>';
    }

}
```

This may or may not be what you are looking for, but basically.. pass the getData function with the current index of the array, say 30 - getData(30); then the function will echo the next 10 contents based on the current index and the max index being 10 more than the current.

['content{$x}'] is a neat little way of directly inserting a variable / object into a string.

Comment: Hi, i edited my post to be more clear, the array is multidimensional, i need to show eg: 10 blocks of `.mycontents_xx` at time  (the number of `$comment['content...'];` is the same in each array, thanks

Comment: Then you can get the .mycontents_xx from different keys by using     myArray[1]['content1] ... myArray[5]['content1'] This will let you get the same data field names out of different index of the array.

Comment: .@Nicholas Mordecai - I get an error if i use: `function getData(currentIndex) {[...]}`, I can't try... `syntax error, unexpected ')'` at the first line

Comment: .@Nicholas Mordecai - Since is inside a fereach loop (i guess... ) i get this error: `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getData() (previously declared...`

Comment: How are you calling this method?

Comment: .@Nicholas Mordecai inside the foreach loop in the `<!-- write content -->` section, I don't understand your code, `currentIndex` and `maxIndex` give me errors, I'm, using in this way (but I get the error mentioned above) : `
$currentIndex = 20;
function getData($currentIndex) {
   $maxIndex = $currentIndex + 10;
   for($x = $currentIndex; $x < $maxIndex; $x++) {
    echo '<div class="'. $comment['content{$x}'] .'"><p>Content..'..'</p></div>';} }`

Comment: .@Nicholas Mordecai - Thanks for your answer. I don't know if my example was clear enough... I updated my post once again. Basically i'm retrieving a JSON content from a php call using some custom API. The arrays are all social posts. The code I'm using at the moment displays all of them at once when the page is loaded. I Would like to show them 10 or 20 at time, depending on my need. Hope now is clear. Thanks again.